Why would a person choose to be female in a medieval, patriarchal society?
My world is effectively a copy of the real world circa 11th Century AD. With one key difference. On each persons' 14th Birthday, they can change their appearance to become any humanoid appearance they desire. Once they make a decision, it is permanent.
Given all the hardships and restrictions women had in pre-industrial times, why would anybody choose to be a woman? Being a man means you're larger, stronger, have a lot more professions available, unlikely to be ravished, and are taken seriously. Sons are also valued more than daughters in many Asian societies.
Of course, all societies need women or otherwise humans cannot reproduce. So, in order for a society to last, close to half of the population needs to choose being a woman. But most families prefer having sons to daughters. You can see this trend in even modern-day China or India or historical Arabia where baby daughters were left to die. In real life, you can't choose your sex or appearance, but in this story, or in a game, you can. In real life, stealing women from other tribes is a possibility, but if those tribes are mostly men, that isn't an option.
How could a medieval patriarchal society like the Delhi Sultanate entice people to be women?

such a world won't have a super sexist society, since everyone knows they could be the other, thoe things were common in our history becasue you could not change it nor was seeing things from the alternative perspectice easy.

You are not thinking, like, at all .. what is valued depends entirely on supply and demand, in the starting point you have you assume no one will value being a woman, OK then, so everyone chooses to be male, then there are no women, no new children, the men go without partners, the social value of women rises exponentially, women become valued above all else and get to call all the shots as a result, next group coming up on 14 find the rewards available to women are massively more than for men, problem solved.

Could you edit the title to match the body? Else people get the idea that it's about the choice of a character - which would be off-topic.

The Delhi Sultanate did not exist in the 11th century. (It came into being in the 13th century.) Delhi was not a particularly important city in the 11th century.

VTC:Not About Worldbuilding per the [help]. The [help/on-topic] states, If ... you aren’t sure what a character (be it an individual or organization) should do, that is out of scope for the site. Questions about choices and motivations are off-topic as they are always story-based, which means there are no wrong answers as you can always write your story to embrace any solution you want.

@Escapeddentalpatient. It doesn't matter. Whether the question is about the person/organization making the choice or the person/organization offering the choice (motivation...) it's still off-topic because any solution can be written into the story. We're not talking about a story-independent world rule and, as the good book says, When asking questions keep in mind that the goal of the site is to help you build your world, not to tell your story.

1.  What makes you think being a man is all that easy? Are you not aware that there were plenty of restrictions on men as well? Men really had no more choices in profession than women had. They had no more social mobility.

2.  In the body of your question, you talk about "changing appearances" and then later delve into reproduction. Is your question focused on social cosplay or is this actually some kind of physiological & genetic transmutation, possibly involving magic?

"Become any humanoid appearance they desire" you say? I think I'll turn 14 and become the Incredible Hulk, just with different equipment under the purple shorts. Pregnancy will no longer be any risk at all. Meanwhile I'll be plowing ten fields a day and chopping down trees with a single swing of an ax. It may not look like it, but 9ft tall and 1000kg of green-skinned muscle is what the ideal woman looks like.

Economics 101
Basic economics says that when a good becomes scarce (when supply decreases relative to demand), it goes up in value. It's kind of uncomfortable referring to people as "goods", but the principle applies. Society needs women, but more to the point, lots of men want women. Medieval men too, or we wouldn't be here. Medieval men want children to help them work the fields, and that, again, means women.
So what happens if everyone starts choosing to be male? To put it crudely, the supply curve shifts left and the price of women goes up. What does this mean practically? First, you'll start to see incentives (financial and otherwise) and likely also coercion to choose female. Second, given a shortage of women, their bargaining power goes up considerably. If I don't want to lose my wife, I'd better take care of her because half the men in the village are just waiting to take her as soon as she gets fed up with me. In modern terms, your average woman has gone from McDonald's burger flipper to highly qualified C++ programmer. Women now have a very privileged position, and that creates a strong incentive for more people to choose female. That, in turn, increases the female population, reducing the effect above. Eventually, your society will reach an equilibrium in which it becomes less patriarchal and the male to female ratio goes up by at most a few percentage points.
I think that as it is you're overestimating the patriarchy of the Middle Ages and seriously underestimating the advantages of being female - other answers have already addressed that, so I won't repeat it. But even if we accept the feminist patriarchal oppression narrative, economic principles dictate that this situation couldn't survive for long in a world with your feature.

"So what happens if everyone starts choosing to be male? .. the supply curve shifts .. and the price of women goes up. What does this mean practically .. In modern terms, your average woman has gone from McDonald's burger flipper to highly qualified C++ programmer. Women now have a very privileged position, and that creates a strong incentive for more people to choose female" precisely  OPs premise is entirely flawed as a result, his perceived "problem" is self correcting and can't even exist in the long term.

@Pelinore exactly, and others commented that, but I thought it was worth an answer explaining why. The OP kind of has a point in that if women are severely disadvantaged, it will shift the gender balance, but back of the napkin I don't think it can go much beyond 55-45 male-female. 60-40 already leaves a third of men without partners, and that seems just a bit too much to be stable long-term.

Put down the Feminist revision of History
Now, sure Men 'Had all the power', but you know what they also had...
All the Responsibility
This is what often gets omitted - Your village under attack - As a Man it is your responsibility to fight, to the death, to defend - or very bad things happen to you and your family.
As a Man, you are just as oppressed by your circumstances, eeking out a living in difficult times, doing manual labour for 10+ hours a day.
Some people dont want that.
Furthermore - The notion that Women did not have any power is nonsense. Let me explain, I have been married for 10+ years.
It is true that I am the ultimate authority in the household. I am (by far) the majority bread winner, So certain things are dictated by Me, My Job and my Salary.
When the kids start acting up, they will try things with my Wife that they wont dare try with me because I am bigger, stronger, scarier and my voice is significantly louder.
This means that there are some decisions that what I say goes, goes. I have the final say.
So far, what I have described probably sounds like something out of the 1950s. And in some ways, it is.
But there is a Flipside - I delegate a lot of authority around the running of the household to my Wife, I also do a lot of things that I would personally not rather do, but because they make my Wife happy and therefore make me happy.
She decides where we are going on family vacations, where we spend christmas, which friends we are seeing etc. If she decides that she doesnt like how the Dining room looks, it is my responsibility to get the paint, strip the walls back and prep them to be re-painted.
This is what is left out. So yes, whilst I, in true Patriarchal fashion, am the head of the household and get to make the big strategic decisions because I am the one ultimately who is ultimately responsible for those decisions... My Wife (who I love deeply) has a lot of power and influence over me and over the running of the house.
That power and influence is not to be scoffed at - and some people will absolutely choose the latter.
TL;DR - Not everyone wants wants the weight of responsibility on their shoulders and even in a patriarchal household, The Woman of the house wields significant power and influence

"With my manly authority I command you to take all of my money and figure out what to do it!"  <- how 90% of households have worked since the beginning of time.

@Nosajimiki - Looks at my Bank balance... cries

Except for a certain very hazardous responsibility without which there wouldn't be any more men or women after a few decades.

@gs You know that a lot of women actually enjoy and look forward to pregnancy.  My wife only wanted 1 kid when we got married, but after the first one, she missed being pregnant and decided she wanted 2 more.  People old enough to remember a time before social media and the internet remember that most people used to speak fondly of pregnancy. Modern women fear it a lot more, even though they die of it a lot less.

@Nosajimiki I agree with what you said, but if we're talking about a medieval society of normal humans, pregnancy is about a 1% risk of death (not including other injuries). Not quite the same thing as a man who enjoys and looks forward to combat, but on the same order of magnitude and imo suggesting similar valor.

@gs Great, now I can't get the mental image of a klingon women laboring while screaming "It's a good day to die." out of my head.

You missed quite a few other things: women had no duty in fire watch, guard watch (especially night watch), manning the watchtowers and/or sentry duty, exempt from mandatory work on maintenance of defenses and utilities (such as they were)... They usually also didn't pay any personal taxes. Also, working hours are misleading - women usually worked more hours during day, but it was way less demanding tasks in terms of manual labor... OP's misconceptions are so many, that suffice to say, after Dr. Peterson: "for 90% of human history 95% of men and women were oppressed equally horribly"

Of course no person would choose to be female in a medieval, patriarchal society. On the other hand, the society developed by human-like beings who get to choose their sex will never be either medieval or strongly patriarchal.
Frame challenge (sort of)
The question is about stuff happening in "a copy of the real world circa 11th century", except it is not: people get to choose their sex at 14 years of age.
This is flat out impossible.
I don't mean that this is impossible from a biological point of view. I mean that this fundamentally impossible. Those people are not humans. They are fundamentally different. Being fundamentally different people there is no way that they would follow the same path of historical development as us regular humans.
The society of those beings which looks like us but who get to choose their sex at age 14 will not be similar to a human society at any stage of historical development.
The question then goes on to speak about a "medieval patriarchal society like the Delhi Sultanate". Setting aside the minor fact that the Delhi Sultanate did not exist in the 11th century, the big problem is that in a society of beings which get to choose their sex at age 14 the patriarchal aspects, if any, would be much more attenuated than in the history of some human societies. Because, you know, you need to get people to choose to be women. In the 11th century, in the 10th century, in the 9th century, in the 1st century, in the 8th century before the common era, in the bronze age, and in the stone age. If the society is to make it to the 11th century, people had to be willing to choose to be women for hundreds of thousands of years.
If the society is to make it to the 11th century, people had to be willing to choose to be women since always. So that no, the society could not possible evolve towards the harder forms of patriarchy seen in the history of some human societies, simply because those societies where people don't want to be women would go extinct.
Mythological sidebar
In the antiquity, one of the most striking differences between the Roman society and pretty much everybody else around them, except the Etruscans, was the relatively high social status of women. Roman women had to freely express their consent in order to be married, they were not confined in the home, they could engage in trade and so on. In order to explain this relatively high status of women in their society the Romans used the myth of the abduction of the Sabine women.
Long story short, when Rome was founded by Romulus (and the late lamented Remus), it was a city of men. No women. So they had to get themselves some women in order to secure a future for the city. Through devious means they abducted some of the daughters of their Sabine neighbours. Of course, the abductees were indignant and quite hostile to the idea of becoming the wives of their abductors, and here comes the twist. Romulus himself negotiated with the abducted women, and convinced them to accept to be married to the Romans and in exchange the Romans would guarantee that Roman women would enjoy all the freedoms which set Rome aside from the surrounding societies.
It worked very well, I would say.
(The real historical explanation is that Rome was originally maybe not exactly an Etruscan city, but at least it was ruled by Etruscan kings and had a large proportion of Etruscan population. The high social status of women was inherited by Rome from its Etruscan past. But it is a great myth.)

"If the society is to make it to the 11th century, people had to be willing to choose to be women since always. So that no, the society could not possible evolve towards the harder forms of patriarchy seen in the history of some human societies, simply because those societies where people don't want to be women would go extinct"

Exactly. As it turns out, females are important to species propagation [citation needed].

This is a misrepresentation of Roman women. They were still under Pater Familia law meaning that a husband legally ruled his wife.  Also Roman women could not vote, hold political offices, or speak in temples.  Yes, they had more rights than Greek women, especially if they were unmarried, but it was still a Patriarchal society.

That said, the Romans still saw their system as fair to women, even if it was not equal.  This is because for every bit of authority men held, they also had greater responsibilities.  Children belonged to men; so, in the case of a divorce, they were required to raise the child by themselves.  A man could be convicted for the crimes of his wife or child.  Only a man could be conscripted.  Etc.  So, it is possible and even probable to see at least some patreachies emerge which yield a blend of men and women.

@Nosajimiki: (1) Everybody was in the power of the pater familias. Both men and women. A man becoming married had no impact whatsoever of his status of subject to the pater familias or sui juris. (2) The familial status of married women depended on whether the marriage was "religious" (cum manu, confarreatio) or "liberal" (sine manu, coëmptio). In older days the two forms or marriage competed, but from the 2nd century BCE onwards marriages cum manu became rarer and rarer. A woman in a marriage sine manu had no relationship with the pater familias of her hustband's family.

@Nosajimiki: And I did say relatively high social status, did I not?

@AlexP fair enough.

I suggest that the “one small change” you’re introducing is enough to break quite a lot of that society. The personal choices for future were few. If you start from 11th century Europe model, I think your characters will be assigned a gender at age 14, much as they were historically assigned an apprenticeship, a feudal lord to rule them, and, often, an assigned spouse. There’s no need for incentivizing anyone to choose.
I do not know as much about the rest of the world in that time period, but my impression is this would be true all over. Family and clan decided individual destiny far more than it does in USA today.

@Pelinore various inducements for social conformity exist. See church attendance or serving in military for plenty of examples of assigning choices back in that era. Failure to conform was (is in many places but less common) often lethal.

"Failure to conform was .. often lethal" .. the sort of coercion you are talking about is the very thing that would encourage and provoke a choice to be physically stronger rather than weaker in anyone not under your immediate physical control at the moment of choice, so can be expected to be counterproductive at scale in any medieval or earlier society lacking some fairly modern and very dystopian types of record keeping, surveillance, control and coercion .. just wouldn't work and individuals aside would tend to have the opposite of the (presumed) desired effect on a societal level.

"I suggest that the “one small change” you’re introducing is enough to break quite a lot of that society" You're spot on there though, Alex elaborated on that (correctly in my view) in his answer, it's very unlikely anything like the more extreme forms of patriarchy could ever develop for a species such as this.

The Patriarchy did not benefit most men
Patriarchy simply means that the ruling class are men... so if you are in that upper 1% of the population, then sure, it makes a lot of sense to choose to be a man, but you are forgetting about the remaining 99% of the population.
The 11th Century AD was a very hard time to be a man.  Yes you are stronger, but being a men meant that you were REQUIRED to use that strength for the survival of yourself and your family.  Parents did not want sons because boys enjoyed more freedom.  They wanted them because they were free slave labor to work the family farm after the father was too worn out from years of back breaking labor to keep going.  If you were a 14 year old boy, chances are you were already working 8-16 hours a day in the sun on your parent's farm doing heavy labor vs 14 year old girls who got to stay inside and focus their efforts on weaving, baking, and all of the other light duty work of the household.
This is before you consider how dangerous it was to be a man.  If your livestock was being eaten by a pack of wolves, it was your job to risk your life to chase them off.  If your lord goes to war, you will be enlisted to go fight in it.  When Vikings attack out of nowhere, you are dead: just dead.  One day you are toiling in your field, and you find yourself outnumbered 20 to 1 by guys with spears, armor, and possibly horsemen... there is no surviving that.  Sure, the women might get raped or even abducted, but more often than not, they will live and you will die.
Child bearing is less dangerous than you may assume
The biggest "risk" an 11th century woman faces is childbirth, but that risk is highly exaggerated by modern culture because we often cite the most extreme statistics which only applied to a small % of the population.  If you lived in an urban area (about 10% of the population), then it is true that childbirth was dangerous because the constant exposure to smog, poor sanitation, and poor nutrition lead to compromised immune systems that made childbirth more dangerous.  In medieval cities, as many as 5% of pregnancies ended in the mother's death; so, it would be reasonable for a lot of people in cities to choose to be men.
A lot of noble women also died in childbirth with about 1.3% of pregnancies ending in the mother's death, but this number was likely higher than average as well because of increased issues related to incest and bad medical practices based on the Greek 4 Humors system whereas peasants mostly relied Celtic inspired herbology and midwifery practices which are today known to be a significantly superior form of medicine.
But... the other ~90% of women who lived in rural areas actually enjoyed very few genetic or communicable diseases, much better air quality and nutrition, and they used non-invasive midwifery practices to support laboring women.  When we look at similar rural populations today like those found in Africa, Vietnam, or the Amish communities of North America that still practice very similar traditions to 11th century peasants, we see a very different story.  These places have MMRs between about 0.1-0.01% suggesting that in Medieval times, child birth could have been almost as safe for rural women as it is for modern women who give birth in hospitals today.  These births also have way fewer complications than modern births because C-sections, spinal taps, and other Modern interventions that cause most modern issues did not exist yet.
That said, there is one last factor that historians widely believed contributed to higher MMRs in the medieval period than these comparable modern societies which was the lower age of maturity.  Girls who give birth before their hips are finished forming are at a MUCH higher risk of death.  Most medieval and Maternal Mortalities can be attributed to girls between the age of 9-14 becoming pregnant before their bodies could handle it, but your setting solves this. By saying that your people A: Don't become childbearing women until they are 14 and B: Can have a lot of control over their physical appearance meaning they can make sure their female forms are suitable for bearing children safely, you've ensured a much lower MMR than actual medieval women had.
The real question should be "How do you convince enough peasants to become men?" since this setting does a lot more to mitigate the hazards of womanhood than it does for manhood.

While this is already a great answer as is, it's worth noting that even among the 1%, there were quite a few female rulers (Eleanor of Aquitaine is the classic example but not the only one) and plenty more who may not have been rulers, but still were able to play the political games and exert plenty of influence. The 1% were probably less patriarchal than the 99%.

wait you think the Amish don't use hospitals? So you are using numbers from people who use modern medicine, and nothing like the medieval era and thus useless.  If we look at actual numbers rural areas have about 3 times the maternal mortality rate, with education having an even bigger effect. https://www.thelancet.com/journals/eclinm/article/PIIS2589-5370(24)00232-3/fulltext#:~:text=We%20find%20large%20subgroup%20differences%20in%20maternal,low%2C%20middle%2C%20and%20high%20education%20levels%2C%20respectively.

I we look what little actual medieval data exists urbans rates are 1.5-2.5% and 1-1.5% in rural areas so nothing like your numbers and orders of magnitude worse than modern numbers. https://www.routledge.com/Obstetrics-and-Gynaecology-in-Tudor-and-Stuart-England/Eccles/p/book/9780367001964?srsltid=AfmBOoqTuObnvB_CFUCYpBw4T0NndRBs5qTRYoR9HagfDS2EfegTiZUv

@John The study I used as a source specifically compared an Amish population that used traditional midwifery and not obstetricians.  Perhaps some Amish communities use obstetricians, but they were not part of the study.  As for the modern difference in outcomes it is because rural communities still mostly use obstetrician practices, but lack emergency services for when  things go wrong

As for the book you cited, it specifically talks about how the author could not find any actual medieval information, and what he does talk about is the replacement of midwives with doctors.  That said, the author (from what I can tell from the publicly available part of his book) seems to take the side of the physicians and has missed the fact that the transition centered around literal witch hunts and that our early survival statistics were recorded by early physicians and exclude the actual outcomes of midwives.

I tried to backtrace the internet statistic of 1-1.5% when I was writing my answer and found it to in fact be false.  There do not appear to be an records of 11th century mortality rates.  Claims of these MMRs appear to come from 17th-19th century statistics and people have guessed they are the same even though childbirth practices and nutritional availability were very different.

Even places with rampant malnutrition and zero access to doctors today only have a 0.4% MMR suggesting that it was the doctors of the late renaissance/industrial era that boosted the MMR up to those levels.  But when you look at the small pockets of society that exist today that live more or less medieval lifestyles where food is abundant enough to maintain a basic standard of health, MMRs drop to 0.1-0.01% with no modern medical interventions.

@John having reviewed all of your citations, and done some more research you are correct that 0.1-0.01% is probably not realistic in the medieval period, but why it is unrealistic is important for this setting.  Based on human remains, most cases of maternal death were because of women were getting pregnant too young.  A lot of women married and got pregnant between the age of 9-14 which very often ended in death, but this setting says you don't choose your gender until you are 14 AND that you can choose your shape; so, women can just choose to have child bearing hips at 14 and be fine.

@Nosajimiki all amish still use modern medicine, they are against unnessisary technology so they give birth at home, but consider healthcare very much nessisary technology. so even at home they still do so with with medically trained professionals, antibiotics, sterilized equipment and most of the other parts of modern medicine. And if they show any sign of complication they go to a hospitals. The amish fund community funded free hospitals, the only modern medicine they really have a problem with is vaccines.

@Nosajimiki the main cause maternal mortlity is sepsis, and we see something similiar in attempts to reconstruct  deaths in preindustrial mothers. this is not going to be strongly effected by age or shape, but is going to be strongly effected by say not having germ theory, sterile birthing conditions or antibiotics. Also keep in mind women had far more children, 3-4 times as many births, so you have account for that since most numbers of the risk per birth.

Could the rest of us see your sources, I would be geniunely interested to read them, but any source that thinks the amish are a good proxy gor preindustrial medicine deeply flawed.

There wasn't much choice given in medieval times. No one was choosing to be a slave or a serf.
Just mandate that each family must have a certain amount of girls.
Some Polynesian societies had something similar. If the village elders decided a family had too many sons, or grandparents want a girl to look after them a family would be told to bring up one of their sons as a girl. Men and womens work was separated, so if you wanted someone to do the womens work, you needed a girl. They weren't given a choice, the choice was made for them.
It still happens today.

To Quickly Replenish Numbers During War or Times of Mass Death
Let's step away from the notion of individuals and look from the perspective of a whole community as an entity.
You have to understand: Most people would never willingly choose to become the opposite sex(unless they're predisposed to) so what can make men willingly become women? When the culture requires it.
Humans have survival instincts and so do cultures. When a culture's population is rapidly dropping from a war, genocide, disease, and so on, it is imperative for it to prioritize its continuation. This is to ensure its survival.
In this specific case, this survival instinct of the community would manifest as a temporary reverence of transforming into a woman. This would likely be treated as a deeply selfless act to convince men into becoming women.

the idea of a nation was barely somthing monst people would ever even think about at the time. also thats group selection wich doesn't work, evolution is perfectly happy to drive a group extenct to the temporary benefit of the members.

@John True. I slightly adjusted nations to cultures in general.

There are already innate benefits to being a woman like living longer or no baldness or no groin strikes or the ability to birth children. That and girls born into this world could just stick with their birth gender due to inertia.
If an otherwise patriarchal society needed more of its citizens to choose being a woman, they could use a variety of carrot-and-stick methods. The carrot being women not getting drafted, doing less physical work, and the prospect of marrying a rich man. The stick being that kids who committed felonies or are just unlucky after drawing sticks are forced to choose womanhood after turning 14. If they disobey, they are either executed or exiled.

if you think groin strikes don't work on women you should ask a woman. also women did not live longer in the past, childbirth added a big death risk reducing the number dramatically.

@John that is a modern misconception.  Childbirth was mostly only dangerous in urban areas where everyone's health was routinely compromised by poor sanitation, nutrition and air quality.  In rural areas where women tended to be healthier, death in childbirth was very rare. Most of the recorded statistics we have come from medieval cities with mortality rates as high as 1 in 5 women, but in rural places today without access to Western Medicine, we only see death rates between 0.1-0.01% of childbirths.

@Nosajimiki don't access to western medicne or don't have access to the full swuite of western medicine. we are comparing to a leach and bloodletting medical theory afterall.  also that is still drastically poorer than modern numbers, 0.000223 That is still a very significant risk of death.

@Nosajimiki also what makes you think you would not be an urban woman? And actual medival numbers show men lived about 4 years longer than women on average, with childbirth being a major contributing cause. https://academic.oup.com/ije/article/34/6/1435/707557 and https://www.soa.org/globalassets/assets/library/research/transactions-of-society-of-actuaries/1989/january/tsa89v414.pdf
